# Custom live Linux distro

Tags: linux, networking, livecd, bootable-media

How can I make a bootable CD / DVD / USB (read only) after setting my non-broadcasted SID and installing specific applications (Closed source FLASH if needed)?  But still act like a Live CD (have all of the drivers available, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an application called [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/). It's a system backup tool that you can also use to make your own linux remix. Remastersys is mainly used with Ubuntu and its derivatives but it does have alternatives for different distros - PCLinuxOS (remasterme), Fedora (Revisor) etc. It has a simple GUI with which you can make your distro along with your programs and application settings. Here are a few guides to get you started:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/customize-distro-remastersys
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remastersys.html
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-with-remastersys.html

You can download Remastersys from here:
http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

Comment: I'll check it out.